# How to link against stdc++ library in platformIO

Tags: c++, linker, libstdc++, esp8266

I am developing for the esp8266 using platformIO, which in turn uses the esp8266 arduino core. The default build does not link against the stdc++ library, so I cannot use std:map. I can successfully compile my sketch in the arduino IDE by modifying the linker setting as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33450946/esp8266-for-arduino-ide-xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc-and-stdmap-linking-error), I just need to achieve the same thing in platform IO. I have tried adding "stdc++" to the LIBS array in the espressif.py builder script to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was an error in PlatformIO due to library linking order. One of the team members wrote a fix that will prsesumably be merged into the main distro soon. Details and link to working build are [here](https://github.com/platformio/platformio/issues/503).